How to prevent requests from altering database at the same time?
I have two requests from the client that can be held pending and executed simultaneously for a user. The two requests check the user's balance; if sufficient, it decrements the balance and then returns a response.
...
 const getUserBalance =  await balance.findOne({ where: { userId: getUser.id } }, {lock:true, transaction: t});
   
    if(getUserBalance < getAmount){
        res.status(403).json({
            "message": "Insufficient balance"

        });
        return false
    }
     await Balance.decrement('balance', { by: getAmount, where: {  userId: getUser.id } }, {lock:true, transaction: t})
...

This works fine until the user has, for instance, a balance of $10 and both requests have $10 amounts each. Both requests will go through, negating the balance to —$10. I have used transaction and lock, but can't get it to work which is to return insufficient for the second request. Any ideas on how to go about this.

Use a transaction around the two operations.

I don't think this is how locks work in sequalize, see https://sequelize.org/api/v7/enums/_sequelize_core.index.lock

Still the same thing @Barmar

Then you're not doing it right. You need to acquire the lock before assigning getUserBalance, and clear it after decrementing.
